# Defining a graded ring structure on $\bigoplus_{i} \text{Ext}^i (A,A)$

Tags: homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, cohomology, homology, graded-rings-modules

I read that, using the fact that $\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(P_{\bullet} ,Q_{\bullet}))$ can by used to compute $\text{Ext}^* (A,B)$ (which I understand), we can give $\bigoplus_{i} \text{Ext}^i (A,A)$ the structure of a graded ring, considering elements of $\text{Ext}^i (A,A)$ as chain maps $P_{\bullet}\rightarrow Q_{\bullet}[i]$ modulo homotopy (where $[i]$ denotes a shift by $i$ places) and the ring structure is given by composing these. Apparently this follows as, using the total chain complex, we get that composition of homomorphisms $\circ :\text{Hom}(A,B)\otimes \text{Hom}(B,C)\rightarrow \text{Hom}(A,C)$ induces a well-defined map $\text{Ext}^i (A,B)\otimes \text{Ext}^j (B,C)\rightarrow \text{Ext}^{i+j} (A,C)$ and as we can identify cycles in $\text{Tot}^{\prod}(\text{Hom}(P_{\bullet} ,Q_{\bullet}))$ with these maps.

Could anyone please explain to me how this identification works and why we can identify $\text{Ext}^i(A,A)$ with the maps in this way.

Comment: What's your definition of $\operatorname{Ext}$? (I am not sure this is research-level.)

Comment: [Wikipedia: Yoneda product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoneda_product).